# Any Way To Check For Client Peer Certificate Without Throwing Exception?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am writing a server which will optionally (depending on the client) will require a client-side certificate. Clients that provide certs and clients that don't provide certs will need to  connect to the server via the same server port.

So that I can support both types of clients on the SSLContext I will call "setWantClientAuth(true)". After a client SSLSession is negotiated I want to go get the client certificate chain if it is available. The only way I see to get the client-certificate chain is via "sslSession.getPeerCertificates()" which unfortunately will throw an exception if the client did not provide a cert.

Is there any other way to determine if the client certificates were provided before calling getPeerCertificates so I can avoid the Exception for clients that don't provide a cert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing an exception in this case is just part of the API contract of [`getPeerCertificate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getPeerCertificates%28%29):

> Throws:
>       SSLPeerUnverifiedException - if the peer's identity has not been verified

The traditional way to handle the absence of client authentication is simply to catch this exception. You can look at [Apache Tomcat's `JSSESupport` implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.coyote/com.springsource.org.apache.coyote/6.0.24/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/jsse/JSSESupport.java) for example.

(They catch `Throwable` in this version, whereas you might just want to catch `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`.)

Comment: I know it is part of the contract. I just hate exceptions being thrown in non-error conditions (i.e. it is only an error if I expected a certificate but didn't get it). In my situation I don't know when I call getPeerCertificate whether the cert is required (or not).

Comment: I get your point. This is one of the cases where it's a grey area. By default, `getPeerCertificate()` assumes that not having a cert should be an exceptional case. This is probably a design choice to force API users to make an active choice of catching that exception, when you don't need a cert, rather than continuing with the normal flow implicitly if you really needed a cert. It also reflects the fact that you're trying to get something that hasn't initialised. Why it hasn't been initialised is up for you to know, not this independent part of the API (you could trigger renegotiation for ex).

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming that there is no way around this. I will just catch and eat the Exception.

Comment: @Gareth, I can't remember any other solutions, but maybe there is one. You don't have to accept my answer so soon, feel free to wait if there are better answers.

Comment: It is OK. If someone provides a better answer I will change it.

Comment: Well it is 10+ years later and looking at the latest JDK (17) code this is still the case. We need a better API.